# Change database connection - Moodle

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, moodle, lms

I have a moodle instance successfully running using AWS RDS (MySQL) as the database. For some reason had to change the RDS (MariaDB). so I tried the following steps:

1. Took a backup of the working database (MySQL)
2. Restored in the new RDS (MariaDB)
3. Changed the connection string in the config
4. Restarted the moodle instance

But moodle is now throwing an error related to DB connection.

```
Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running 
properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have 
been correctly specified in config.php
```

How can I solve this issue? Did I miss any steps? Any pointers would be helpful.

### Update:

Source DB engine: MySQL

Target DB engine: MariaDB

### Update: Current config.php file

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

  unset($CFG);
  global $CFG;
  $CFG = new stdClass();

  $CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
  $CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
  $CFG->dbhost    = 'xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com';
  $CFG->dbname    = 'xxx_lms';
  $CFG->dbuser    = 'admin';
  $CFG->dbpass    = 'uAnaxxxxxxxx';
  $CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
  $CFG->dboptions = array (
       'dbpersist' => 0,
       'dbport' => '',
       'dbsocket' => '',
       'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  );

  $CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.23';
  $CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/moodledata';
  $CFG->admin     = 'admin';
  $CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

  require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');
```

Comment: Did you update `config.php` to `$CFG->dbtype = 'mariadb';` ?

Comment: Yes. I'm still getting the same error. I have updated my original post with the contents from my current 'config.php' file. Thank you

Comment: Can you connect from the command line? `mysql -u [username] -p -h [hostname] database_name` or maybe try some php code on the server, so it rules out Moodle `$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);`